# How do I keep the grid lines when converting pdf to images using iText7

Tags: image, pdf, itext7

I have a grid lined table in my pdf document that was converted from ms word. When I use iText7 to convert the pdf to an image, the grid lines in the pdf document disappear in the image.  How do I make the grid lines appear in the image?  I also noticed the font does not convert correctly in some areas when using iText7.  When I use the iTextSharp library, everything works great and converts properly line for line and all fonts appear exact. If you want to know how to get iTextSharp and iText7 to work in Azure functions, ping me.

Below is the code I found on github.  I am using it to do the conversion.

```
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.Listener;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using itext.pdfimage.Models;
using itext.pdfimage.Extensions;
using System.Threading;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing.Text;

namespace itext.pdfimage
{

    public class PdfToImageConverter
    {
        private static int counter;

        //Main Function to Call
        public void ConvertToImage( MemoryStream pdf, String filename )
        {
            pdf.Position = 0;

            var reader = new PdfReader( pdf );
            var pdfDocument = new PdfDocument( reader );
            var bitmaps = pdfDocument.ConvertToBitmaps();
            var i = 1;

            foreach ( var bitmap in bitmaps )
            {
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                bitmap.Save( filename, ImageFormat.Png );

                stream.Dispose();
                bitmap.Dispose();
                i++;
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<Bitmap> ConvertToBitmaps( PdfDocument pdfDocument )
        {
            counter = 0;

            var numberOfPages = pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages();

            for ( var i = 1; i <= numberOfPages; i++ )
            {
                var currentPage = pdfDocument.GetPage( i );

                yield return ConvertToBitmap( currentPage );
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<Stream> ConvertToJpgStreams( PdfDocument pdfDocument )
        {
            foreach ( var bmp in ConvertToBitmaps( pdfDocument ) )
            {
                using ( var ms = new MemoryStream() )
                {
                    bmp.Save( ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg );
                    yield return ms;
                }
                bmp.Dispose();
            }
        }

        public Bitmap ConvertToBitmap( PdfPage pdfPage )
        {
            var rotation = pdfPage.GetRotation();

            var chunkDictionairy = new SortedDictionary<float, IChunk>();

            FilteredEventListener listener = new FilteredEventListener();
            listener.AttachEventListener( new TextListener( chunkDictionairy, IncreaseCounter ) );
            listener.AttachEventListener( new ImageListener( chunkDictionairy, IncreaseCounter ) );
            PdfCanvasProcessor processor = new PdfCanvasProcessor( listener );
            processor.ProcessPageContent( pdfPage );

            //var size = currentPage.GetPageSizeWithRotation();
            var size = pdfPage.GetPageSize();

            var width = size.GetWidth().PointsToPixels();
            var height = size.GetHeight().PointsToPixels();

            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap( width, height );
            using ( Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage( bmp ) )
            {
                g.FillRectangle( Brushes.White, 0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height );

                g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                g.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixelGridFit;

                foreach ( var chunk in chunkDictionairy )
                {
                    g.ResetTransform();

                    g.RotateTransform( -rotation );

                    if ( chunk.Value is Models.ImageChunk imageChunk )
                    {
                        var imgW = imageChunk.W.PointsToPixels();
                        var imgH = imageChunk.H.PointsToPixels();
                        var imgX = imageChunk.X.PointsToPixels();
                        var imgY = ( size.GetHeight() - imageChunk.Y - imageChunk.H ).PointsToPixels();

                        g.TranslateTransform( imgX, imgY, MatrixOrder.Append );
                        g.DrawImage( imageChunk.Image, 0, 0, imgW, imgH );
                        imageChunk.Image.Dispose();
                    }
                    else if ( chunk.Value is Models.TextChunk textChunk )
                    {
                        var chunkX = textChunk.Rect.GetX().PointsToPixels();
                        var chunkY = bmp.Height - textChunk.Rect.GetY().PointsToPixels();

                        var fontSize = textChunk.FontSize.PointsToPixels();

                        Font font;
                        try
                        {
                            font = new Font( textChunk.FontFamily, fontSize, textChunk.FontStyle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel );
                        }
                        catch ( Exception ex )
                        {
                            //log error

                            font = new Font( "Calibri", 11, textChunk.FontStyle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel );
                        }

                        g.TranslateTransform( chunkX, chunkY, MatrixOrder.Append );

                        //g.DrawString(textChunk.Text, font, new SolidBrush(textChunk.Color), chunkX, chunkY);
                        g.DrawString( textChunk.Text, font, new SolidBrush( textChunk.Color ), 0, 0 );
                    }
                }

                g.Flush();
            }

            return bmp;
        }

        public Stream ConvertToJpgStream( PdfPage pdfPage )
        {
            var bmp = ConvertToBitmap( pdfPage );
            using ( var ms = new MemoryStream() )
            {
                bmp.Save( ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg );
                bmp.Dispose();
                return ms;
            }
        }

        private Func<float> IncreaseCounter = () => counter = Interlocked.Increment( ref counter );
    }
}

using iText.IO.Font;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace itext.pdfimage.Extensions
{
    public static class ConvertExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<Bitmap> ConvertToBitmaps( this PdfDocument pdfDocument )
        {
            var converter = new PdfToImageConverter();
            return converter.ConvertToBitmaps( pdfDocument );
        }

        public static Bitmap ConvertPageToBitmap( this PdfPage pdfPage )
        {
            var converter = new PdfToImageConverter();
            return converter.ConvertToBitmap( pdfPage );
        }

        public static IEnumerable<Stream> ConvertToJpgStreams( this PdfDocument pdfDocument )
        {
            var converter = new PdfToImageConverter();
            return converter.ConvertToJpgStreams( pdfDocument );
        }

        public static Stream ConvertPageToJpg( this PdfPage pdfPage )
        {
            var converter = new PdfToImageConverter();
            return converter.ConvertToJpgStream( pdfPage );
        }

        internal static FontStyle GetFontStyle( this FontNames fontNames )
        {
            var fontname = fontNames.GetFontName();
            var fontStyleRegex = Regex.Match( fontname, @"[-,][\w\s]+$" );

            if ( fontStyleRegex.Success )
            {
                var result = fontStyleRegex.Value.ToLower();
                if ( result.Contains( "bold" ) )
                {
                    return FontStyle.Bold;
                }
            }

            return FontStyle.Regular;
        }
    }
}

namespace itext.pdfimage.Extensions
{
    public static class MeasuringExtensions
    {
        //72 points == 1
        //72px x 72px is 1inch x 1inch at a 72dpi resolution

        public static int Dpi { get; set; } = 300;

        public static float PixelsToPoints( this float value, int? dpi = null )
        {
            return value / ( dpi ?? Dpi ) * 72;
        }

        public static int PointsToPixels( this int value, int? dpi = null )
        {
            return PointsToPixels( (float)value );
        }

        public static int PointsToPixels( this float value, int? dpi = null )
        {
            return (int)( value * ( dpi ?? Dpi ) / 72 );
        }
    }
}
```